# How to suppress exit message for google cloud logging

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Google cloud logging is printing out this message when my (python) program exits:

```
Program shutting down, attempting to send 1 queued log entries to Stackdriver Logging...
Waiting up to 5 seconds.
Sent all pending logs.
```

I would like to suppress printing that message. Is there a config setting to control whether the message above does not get printed out when the program exits? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like intended behavior and some of the messages you can found in [source code](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/_modules/google/cloud/logging/handlers/transports/background_thread.html) of cloud logging. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use SyncTransport instead of the default BackgroundThreadTransport

```
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers.transports import SyncTransport
..........
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, name="your_log_name", transport=SyncTransport)
```